# Equivalent for mb_detect_encoding(php) in nodejs?

Tags: php, node.js, character-encoding

I'm translatin a php app to nodejs app and there is a function to detect the encoding of a file. `mb_detect_encoding`

What is the equivalent in nodejs or similar way to find the encoding of a file in nodejs?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating question here, you should search for resolution. Just googled "*nodejs detect encoding*" and here you are: [detect-encoding](https://www.npmjs.com/package/detect-encoding) npm package. I don't know if it's working or not, I only want to encourage you to finding answers on your own.